# check if an element has any attribute from a given array

Tags: javascript, html, attributes

If I have an attribute `disabled`, and I want to check if an element has this attribute before running a function, I can use

```
if element.hasAttribute('disabled')
```

If I have several attributes that relate to the same function, such as

```
attributes = [disabled, something, another]
```

How can I use `if element.hasAttribute('attribute')` to check for any of the attributes in the array?

**Update**:

I actually only have two items in my array, so I did

```
if el.hasAttribute('noink') || el.hasAttribute('disabled')
```

The responses below are also viable and I would use them if I had a larger array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a function

```
function hasAttributes(element, arr) {
    return [].slice.call(element.attributes).some(function(attr) {
        return arr.indexOf(attr.name) !== -1;
    });
}
```

to be used as

```
var attributes = ['disabled', 'something', 'another'];
var element    = document.getElementById('some_id');

var has_attr   = hasAttributes(element, attributes);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/6vq0vLzv/)

Comment: thanks, I may use something like this as an attribute alternative to [classie](https://github.com/desandro/classie) in the future.

Comment: why you use [].slice.call why not Array.slice.call ? is there any difference between these two @adeneo

Comment: Yes, there's a difference, `[].slice.call` is a shortcut for `Array.prototype.slice.call`

Answer (score 0):

apply for loop:

```
  var isAttr=false;
    for(key in attributes){
        if(element.hasAttribute('attribute')){
        console.log('the attribute'+attributes[key]+ 'is attach to element');
        isAttr=true;
       }
    }
 console.log('element has any of array element as attribute:'+isAttr)
```

Comment: interesting, I wouldn't have though of this. I don't have enough attributes to warrant it, though. thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more compact...

```
function hasAttributes(e, l){
    var t = [];
    for(var i in l){
        t.push(e.attributes[l[i]] !== undefined);
    }
    return t;
}
```

use:

```
var myList = ["disabled", "something", "another"];
var myElement = document.getElementById("test");
console.log(hasAttributes(myElement, myList));
```

Or just true false for all or nothing case:

```
function getAttributes(e, l){
    var t = [];
    for(var i in l){
        if(e.attributes[l[i]] === undefined){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**:

I actually only have two items in my array, so I did

```
if el.hasAttribute('noink') || el.hasAttribute('disabled')
```

The responses below are also viable and I would use them if I had a larger array.